# JQuery in a C#/XAML Metro Application

Tags: c#, jquery, xaml, windows-8

Is It possible to use JQuery in C#/XAML metro application? If yes how I can apply a fade in animation to div content using JQuery. I am a student and new to this development environment. Don't know much about programming. If you can give a detailed explanation on this topic it would be great. Thanks in Advance,
Roz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. it is possible, you can add jquery library into your project's local folder and refer the project using  and then you can use the methods in jquery methods in your local html page.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't use it.

Jquery is a java script library for html it does not work with xaml and .net

Here it is [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/62581a73-4bc1-4c1e-ae88-6c92870223c2/can-we-use-jquery-in-a-cxaml-metro-application-?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Hope it clarifies U. Rather than this you can use Javascript in Windwos store app[C#/XAML]

**NOTE:** Please do some search before posting a new question in SO.

Comment: Hi kumar thanks for your answer. Below given is the answer what I am expected for.